# How to mount the drive for use in R Colab

Tags: r, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to use the driver for R colab but it gives the following error

```
if (file.exists("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/_ipython.py")) { 
  install.packages(" R.utils") 
  library("R.utils") 
  library("httr") 
  my_check <- function() {return(TRUE)} 
  reassignInPackage("is_interactive", pkgName = "httr", my_check) 
  options(rlang_interactive=TRUE ) 
}
```

```
drive_auth( 
  email = gargle:: gargle_oauth_email (), 
  path = NULL, 
  scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
  cache = gargle:: gargle_oauth_cache (), 
  use_oob = gargle:: gargle_oob_default () , 
  token = NULL 
)
```

Error in `drive_auth()`:
! Can't get Google credentials
ℹ Are you running googledrive in a non-interactive session? Consider:
• `drive_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials
• Call `drive_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics
ℹ See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
ℹ https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html
Traceback:

1. drive_auth(use_oob = TRUE, cache = TRUE)
2. drive_abort(c("Can't get Google credentials", i = "Are you running googledrive in a non-interactive session? \\n             Consider:",
   .     `*` = "{.fun drive_deauth} to prevent the attempt to get credentials",
   .     `*` = "Call {.fun drive_auth} directly with all necessary specifics",
   .     i = "See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:",
   .     i = "{.url [https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html}"](https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html%7D%22)))
3. cli::cli_abort(message = message, ..., .envir = .envir)
4. rlang::abort(message, ..., call = call, use_cli_format = TRUE,
   .     .frame = .frame)
5. signal_abort(cnd, .file)